Flutter: Cached_Network_Image causing too much memory consumption
i am using Cached_network_image, and it's causing a lot of memory consumption!
I have a large list of data with thumbnails, so I want to cache the thumbnails. But, every time I paginate and my screen is setStated, it runs the whole operation of caching and displaying over, causing unnecessary memory consumption. Plus, if there are 100 thumbnails, it invokes the caching operations for all the 100 images.
Please suggest what better I can do, and if create my custom caching system with Flutter_Cache_Manager, how may I do that? Please help.
Btw, I have tried making my own Caching System and this is what it looks like, but I have the same problem as the Cached_network_Image package does, upon every setState, is rebuilds and executes the whole operation of checking, caching, and displaying an image.
My Custom (Faulty) Caching System:
class Custom_Cached_Image extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;
  final double aspectRatio;
  final CacheManager cacheManager;
  final bool memory;
  final bool isMe;
  final int cacheWidth;
  final int cacheHeight;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final colorProvider;
  final shimmerBaseColor;
  final shimmerHighlightColor;
  const Custom_Cached_Image({super.key, required this.image, required this.aspectRatio, required this.width, required this.cacheManager, required this.memory, required this.isMe, required this.cacheWidth, required this.cacheHeight, required this.height, required this.colorProvider, this.shimmerBaseColor, this.shimmerHighlightColor});

  @override
  State<Custom_Cached_Image> createState() => _Custom_Cached_ImageState();
}

class _Custom_Cached_ImageState extends State<Custom_Cached_Image> {

  String imagePath = "";
  late Color shmBaseClr;
  late Color shmHighLightClr;
  @override
  void initState() {
    var colorProvider1 = Provider.of<themeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    // ---- Shimmer Base Color ----- //
    if(widget.shimmerBaseColor != null) {
      shmBaseClr = widget.shimmerBaseColor;
    } else {
      shmBaseClr = colorProvider1.accentColor;
    }

    // ---- Shimmer Highlight Color ----- //
    if(widget.shimmerHighlightColor != null) {
      shmHighLightClr = widget.shimmerHighlightColor;
    } else {
      shmHighLightClr = colorProvider1.shimmerColor;
    }

    getTheImagePath();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> initImage() async {
    try {
      final _file = await widget.cacheManager.getFileFromCache(widget.image);

      if(_file != null && _file.file.existsSync()) {
        return _file.file.path;
      } else {
        final _nFile = await widget.cacheManager.getSingleFile(widget.image, key: widget.image);
        return _nFile.path;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Image Caching Config: ${e}");
      return "Error Occurred! Please Try Again!";
    }
  }

  getTheImagePath() async {
    try {
      if((imagePath??"").trim().isEmpty) {
        print("Called!");
        if(mounted) {
          imagePath = await initImage();
          if(mounted) {
            setState(() {});
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("Already Called!");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error Caching Image (Custom_Caching_Mechanism) : ${e}");
    }
  }

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    // TODO: implement setState
    if(mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: widget.aspectRatio,
      child: (imagePath??"").trim().isNotEmpty ? Image.file(
        File(imagePath),
        height: widget.height,
        width: widget.width,
        cacheWidth: widget.cacheWidth,
        cacheHeight: widget.cacheHeight,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        errorBuilder: (buildContext, object, stackTrace) {
          return Center(
            child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 24, color: widget.colorProvider.iconColor,),
          );
        },
      ) : Center(
        child: Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: shmBaseClr,
          highlightColor: shmHighLightClr,
          child: Container(
            color: widget.colorProvider.accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

